Token swap on Uniswap fails with V2TooLittleReceived even with Max fee higher than gas price
Can someone please explain why these Ethereum transactions failed according to Etherscan?
I am aware that using Uniswap involves more computation work than just transferring between EOAs, but I just can't figure out from the etherscan status why these transactions failed with V2TooLittleReceived.
The Max fee the sender was willing to pay is greater than the gas price of the transaction, so why did the transaction fail with V2TooLittleReceived?
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa5f4ceabcbac82715d11dfeb2d7a7ce4ff91abbd194037591866b33d78350a1a
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe5e073de9f0d1f87c8139eb7cd15332d6134c9e67f9ee2a4ea70c340fc6dbd99
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6caf044cd48f703d61054166370c54a1d6a88767fe8f62b508aa84f785967210

The above error has nothing to do with the max fee or the gas price.
V2TooLittleReceived is a custom error thrown from the Uniswap contract. It's thrown whenever the amount that would have been received is less than the minimum amount specified by the user.
if (amountOut < amountOutMinimum) revert V2TooLittleReceived();
Check your slippage threshold. It's too low for the actual slippage on the swap.

Is there a way to check the values for amountOut and amountOutMinimum that the user had specified for the transaction?

They’re in the swap function call, but deeply nested since it’s being called through the Universal Router and encoded. You can try putting it into something like callthis.link to get the values.
Another way would be to use tenderly.co to simulate the transaction and compare the values

Thank you very much for the suggestion!
